# What are the notable differences between Polaroid Pogo and Polaroid 300?

Tags: polaroid

I'd like to know the diffences that are worth nothing when choosing between [Polaroid Pogo](http://store.polaroid.com/products/0/266909/Instant_Digital_Camera) and [Polaroid 300](http://store.polaroid.com/category/0/354633/Classic_Instant). Considering I am a newbie when it comes to cameras, especially Polaroid, I have no idea whatsoever between the advantages and disadvantages of having one over the other.

Comment: This would help a lot. You may post it as an answer actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'd check out the [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001RIYUJQ) [pages](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003B2GTY0) of each of them.

Aside from price, the biggest difference is the medium: the Pogo is digital, and the 300 uses film. The Pogo will give you the ability to edit a little bit in-camera before printing.

That said, $199 is a lot for a point and shoot with no optical zoom (digital only). 4x digital zoom on a 5MP camera leaves you with a pretty wimpy 0.31 megapixels, on par with 2005-era cell phone cameras. Perhaps a regular compact camera plus something like the [Canon Selphy](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003YL412A) (a portable, battery-powered photo printer) or even the [PoGo Instant Printer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001APNVTQ), which uses the same paper as the Pogo camera, would fit your needs.

Comment: Good point on checking out Amazon. Haven't checked the reviews there yet. Thanks!